# Include/declare two classes which both contain the same resource and name

Tags: puppet

I have two puppet modules `m1` and `m2`. Please see sample modules below with the same resource type and name:

```
class m1 {
  service {'firewalld':
    ensure => 'stopped',
    enable => 'false',
  }
  ... // more resource types
}


class m2 {
  service {'firewalld':
    ensure => 'running',
    enable => 'true',
    hasrestart => true,
    subscribe => Exec['firewall-cmd'],
  }

  package {'httpd':
    ensure => 'present',
  }

  exec { 'firewall-cmd':
    command     => "firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=80/tcp --add-port=443/tcp --permanent",
    path        => "/usr/bin/",
    refreshonly => true,
    subscribe   => Package['httpd'],
  }
  ... // more resource types
}
```

I want to apply both of these modules to multiple nodes. When I try to apply these modules it gives me the error `Duplicate Declaration for resource type`

I am new to puppet. I have tried to design third module with common resource types, and after inheriting this third module `m3` to `m1` and `m2`, it gives me the error `Parameter 'ensure' is already set on Service puppet`

How can I design my modules to get rid of these errors?
I don't want to create a single module, because for some nodes I want to apply only `m1` or `m2` and not both.

Comment: One class is disabling and stopping `firewalld` and the other is enabling and starting `firewalld`. Looking at this from a completely Puppet-agnostic perspective, these are mutually incompatible configurations for a single system. Puppet is doing the right thing here and preventing this impossible state.

Comment: @MattSchuchard - Even I changed the values for those attributes like "ensure" then also I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Each resource can only exist in one place for each node. This is true even if they match.

I would suggest moving resources that are needed by multiple modules to their own module, and `include`ing it from the other modules. In this case, that means creating a `firewalld` module.

Comment: ... and because include-like class declarations are used (which is key), any class parameter customizations for the third module's class(es) are accomplished via automated data binding.